# Peewee execute_sql with escaped characters

Tags: python, peewee

I have wrote a query which has some string replacements. I am trying to update a url in a table but the url has % signs in which causes a `tuple index out of range exception`.

If I print the query and run in manually it works fine but through peewee causes an issue. How can I get round this? I'm guessing this is because the percentage signs?

```
query = """
    update table 
      set url = '%s'
     where id = 1
""" % 'www.example.com?colour=Black%26white'
db.execute_sql(query)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you are currently sharing is **incredibly unsafe**, probably for the same reason as is causing your bug. Please do not use it in production, or you will be hacked.

Generally: you practically never want to use normal string operations like `%`, `+`, or `.format()` to construct a SQL query. Rather, you should to use your SQL API/ORM's specific built-in methods for providing dynamic values for a query. In your case of SQLite in peewee, that looks like this:

```
query = """
    update table 
      set url = ?
     where id = 1
"""
values = ('www.example.com?colour=Black%26white',)
db.execute_sql(query, values)
```

The database engine will automatically take care of any special characters in your data, so you don't need to worry about them. If you *ever* find yourself encountering issues with special characters in your data, it is a **very strong** warning sign that some kind of security issue exists.

This is mentioned in the [Security and SQL Injection](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#security-and-sql-injection) section of peewee's docs.

Comment: Thank you makes a lot of sense. As this is not user facing application, just an internal server script I was getting lazy and not too worried about security. Clearly that was a big mistake.Thanks :)

Comment: That makes sense. There are cases where security isn't a big concern, but I default to **big bold disclaimers** because it's hard to know, and I've seen way too many users ignore less-blatant warnings. Fortunately, it's pretty easy to do the right thing with most tools these days. :)

Comment: Docs have moved, [this](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/query_operators.html#security-and-sql-injection) is the new link.
Quoting:
> By default peewee will parameterize queries, so any parameters passed in by the user will be escaped. The only exception to this rule is if you are writing a raw SQL query or are passing in a `SQL` object which may contain untrusted data. To mitigate this, ensure that any user-defined data is passed in as a query parameter and not part of the actual SQL query.

Answer (score -3):

Wtf are you doing? Peewee supports updates.

```
Table.update(url=new_url).where(Table.id == some_id).execute()
```

Comment: It's a more complex update than just that. Lots of case when's and the playhouse case when's are... Well just horrible!